# Dynamic web project displaying the java code on browser?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, web-applications

I am creating Dynamic web project in eclipse.
Now Following is my java class

```
package com;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FirstProject extends JPanel {
    private Map<Color, Integer> bars = new LinkedHashMap<Color, Integer>();

    /**
     * Add new bar to chart
     * 
     * @param color
     *            color to display bar
     * @param value
     *            size of bar
     */
    public void addBar(Color color, int value) {
        bars.put(color, value);
        repaint();
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (Integer value : bars.values()) {
            max = Math.max(max, value);
        }

        int width = (getWidth() / bars.size()) - 2;
        int x = 1;
        for (Color color : bars.keySet()) {
            int value = bars.get(color);
            int height = (int) ((getHeight() - 5) * ((double) value / max));
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillRect(x, getHeight() - height, width, height);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(x, getHeight() - height, width, height);
            x += (width + 2);
        }
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(bars.size() * 10 + 2, 50);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Bar Chart");
        FirstProject chart = new FirstProject();
        chart.addBar(Color.red, 100);
        chart.addBar(Color.green, 8);
        chart.addBar(Color.blue, 54);
        chart.addBar(Color.black, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(chart);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and following is my web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>com.FirstProject</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>com.FirstProject</welcome-file>

  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>.
```

Now when I run the application the local host displays the entire code as it is on the browser.

How to get the desired output(the bar chart being displayed on browser)?  Am I missing something or am I not following the correct pattern?

Comment: do we use `JPanel` in a dynamic web project? Instead you can use JSPs

Comment: @Abu,,So as to display the barcharts am i supposed to write JSP and then display that???

Comment: `JPanel` is a `swing` component, and if I am not wrong, you cannot use Swing in a web-based project. You can however try using `JApplet`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to display your output,Then you have to use the JSP, Servlet, NOT a JPANEL.
JPanel cannot display data into browser.

You can use the JApplet and the display the code into browser.

You got my point?

Comment: Given it is either 'generate the image on the server side **or** client side' and that breaks down to 'generate the image using JSP/servlet **or** applet' I would recommend JSP/servlet as the best option here.  Leave applets out of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this not the solution to your question, but this may help you to solve your problem.

Striking Difference between Swing and JSP+Servlets

**JSP,Servlets**: They are server-side technology, used for generating HTML pages

**Swing** used for desktop applications (can be used with JApplets)

Answer (score 0):

You are working on JPanel.. JPanel is developed for Desktop Applications..
You have to use Jsp or servlets for working in Web Based Application..
You Have to Use Html Tags for displaying Your Design In web browser..

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has specified swing is desktop app and Jframe cant be used in web application.

You can show only static image on web browser using jfreechart.

IN desktop app using swing u can customize the charts for mouselistner,keyboard listner, tool tips and all....

Jsp can show only static image file.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JavaFX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/index.html) to display the web page.